# difference between java.util.Scanner input = new Scanner () and import Scanner in main class

Tags: java

Can anyone explain the difference of theese two codes?

```
public class radacinaPatrata {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

}
}
```

and this one

```
import java.util. Scanner ();
 public class radacinaPatrata {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = Scanner(System.in);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Also, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/131499/what-are-the-reasons-one-would-use-fully-qualified-class-names-in-source-code

Comment: Perhaps you should read up about Java basics before asking simple questions about syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same , if you have class names conflict ion you can use class with package name.